# Using DHIS 2 API With Jquery Cross domain issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, cross-domain

I'm trying to implement a javascript application which uses the DHIS 2 API. I've spent the whole day trying to authenticate using Jquery.

The API says (https://www.dhis2.org/doc/snapshot/en/user/html/ch32s02.html) you need to use base 64 authentification. I tried to implement that in Jquery but i run into cross domain issues. I have tried authenticating using the DHIS 2 demo (https://apps.dhis2.org/dev/) but unsuccessfully. I then set up a local copy on my local computer but i still run in the same issue as DHIS 2 is running on different port.

I've tried jsonp and CROS but in vain.

Here is the code i'm trying so far

```
$(function(){
  var base_url = "http://apps.dhis2.org/demo/";
  var login = 'dhis-web-commons-security/login.action?authOnly=true';
  var current_user_url = 'api/users.json';
  var params = {
       'j_username':'admin',
      'j_password':'district'
 };


 function base_64_auth(user,password) { 
      var tok = user + ':' + password;
      var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
      return "Basic " + hash;
 }

 var auth = base_64_auth('admin','district');

 $.ajax({
      url : base_url+login,
     data : params,
     type : 'POST',
     dataType : 'text',
     crossDomain : true,
     xhrFields : {
          'withCredentials':true
     },
     beforeSend : function(req) {
          req.setRequestHeader('Authorization',auth);
     },
     success : function(data){
          console.log('authentification succeded');
          alert('success');
          //userInfo();
     },error : function(xhr,type,msg) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(type);
          console.log(msg);
     }
 });

)};
```

I'm using a simple library for base64 encoding www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html#.U9_O2XVdWkA

Checking in the console i see this error :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://apps.dhis2.org/demo/dhis-web-commons-security/login.action?authOnly=true`. The request was redirected to `'http://apps.dhis2.org/demo/dhis-web-commons/security/login.action?failed=true'`, which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

If anyone has ever used the API, i would appreciate his help or if you know any other way (including other languages) i may be able to talk to the API, i may go for it.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain requests are usually blocked by the browser. I'm working with the DHIS2 API as part of a group project myself, and we got around the issue by disabling same-origin policy in chrome, by running:

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security
```

Note that you'll still have to authenticate requests to the demo-server, and that this solution is not ideal in any way. I'm guessing the best way to do it is to deploy the server locally and placing all your files on the server, so that requests happen on the same domain as the server. Also note that when disabling web security in chrome, it may be a good idea to use another browser for mail, facebook, etc.

Answer (score 1):

DHIS version 2.18 has an option to enable CORS. The domains which should be allowed for CORS access can be listed in System settings -> Remote Access

https://www.dhis2.org/218

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.18 DHIS 2 added support for [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) which allows for resource sharing across different origins / domains.

You can set up a white-list of domain names that your DHIS 2 instance will accept requests from under apps > settings > access. In other words, you must define inside DHIS 2 the domains from where you plan to request DHIS 2 data. So if you plan to set up a Web portal retrieving data from DHIS 2 at webportal.org, then you must define webportal.org as a whitelisted CORS domain.

[Docs here](https://www.dhis2.org/doc/snapshot/en/user/html/ch23.html#d5e4424)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following php code:

```
$post_string_b64 = base64_encode("user:password");

$auth = 'Authorization: Basic '.$post_string_b64;

$ch = curl_init("dhis2server/api/dataSets?paging=false");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

then you get a ***json response*** that you could make it readable in the following way:

```
$pattern = '/\{(.+)\}/';

preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);

$json = json_decode($matches[0], true);
```

Code should be self explanatory, but feel free to ask what is unclear,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

@Ajmal A
I can confirm that editing the appropriate CORS settings in *System Settings -> Access -> CORS whitelist* works. We are using DHIS2 version 2.25.

[image: CORS whitelist]
I am working on our client application on `localhost:3000` right now, and after whitelisting, I am now able to fetch data using the following jQuery AJAX call.

```
var apiUrl = "https://<YOUR_URL>/api/<YOUR_RESOURCE>?format=json";
$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields : {
        'withCredentials':true
     },
    dataType : "json",
    username: "<YOUR_USERNAME>",
    password: "<YOUR_PASSWORD>"
})
  .done(function( json ) {
      console.log(json);
  })
  .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
    console.log( "AJAX request failed on " + apiUrl );
    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    console.log( "Status: " + status );
    console.dir( xhr );
  })
  .always(function( xhr, status ) {
    console.log( "AJAX request closed." );
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access from outside DHIS platform (ie., different domain). DHIS does not permit it.
I've also spent two days on it. Then, DHIS volunteer told me this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up calling the API using Java instead of Javascript. It works fine now